# Does a German citizen need a negative covid-19 test to reenter Germany after travel to the United States?

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, germany, covid-19, german-citizens

I have had a friend staying with me for the last week. He is fully vaccinated, as am I and my family, and tomorrow he flies back to Germany.

For some reason, Lufthansa have been saying that his ticket/travel documents are under airport control due to Covid 19. We have been trying to figure out what all this means, and we started to question whether or not he needs a negative Covid test to reenter his home country.

If he does, we need to get an appointment scheduled soon.

Comment: It probably just means that the system requires a human to look at and verify the vaccination-or-test document and/or to confirm that the document actually pertains to the traveler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of this writing, no test is required. According to both [Lufthansa's info page](https://www.lufthansa.com/xx/en/flight-information.html) and [the German Interior Ministry](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/EN/topics/civil-protection/coronavirus/coronavirus-faqs.html;jsessionid=AF52889F73B7D41C4BF6069491EADEC8.1_cid287), travelers entering Germany must in general present a recent covid-19 test *or* proof of vaccination; there is no requirement to have both.

The United States [was previously considered](https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Transport/Archiv_Risikogebiete/EN-Tab.html) a "high-risk area" and so there were some additional requirements for flying from the US to Germany. This designation [was removed](https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Transport/Archiv_Risikogebiete/Risikogebiete_2021-11-12_en.pdf?__blob=publicationFile), however, effective November 14, 2021.

Of course, there is no harm in getting a covid test even if one is not strictly required.

Comment: Note that in some other constellations, a test is required to get out of quarantine. So "can enter without a test" and "faces no restrictions without a test" are different.